# Save and restore nautilus server connection bookmarks

Tags: nautilus, sync, password, ftp, remote

Usually I open Nautilus \ File \ Connect to server.
Enter some authentication data (usually FTP).
Login, go to some folder (usually public_html) and save bookmark to remote server (so later folder can be accessed in few clicks).

Here is my question:
Can this bookmarks (passwords) be saved before reinstalling Ubuntu, and restored later?

Comment: I have reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch twice this year and always have to create all the server bookmarks again, if someone know the answer to this, it would be nice

Answer (score 2):

Just upgraded (manually) from 17.10 to 18.04.1 and - in order to restore my Nautilus bookmarks, I copied the following file from the old setup:

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

Mind you, this likely won't restore passwords for remote server connections (it would be rather unpleasant if these were left lying around in plaintext files); as such, not a full fledged solution, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus uses URIs for bookmarks. File is located in your home directory:

```
~/.gtk-bookmarks
```

Add that file to Ubuntu One and you should be good with locations. Passwords are stored in Passwords and Keys and can be sync'd with a key server. Or you can comment them in the file above.

Example:

```
ftp://{userid}@ftp.site.com/ {Comment}
```