# How to make Nautils forget credentials for deleted bookmarks?

Tags: nautilus, nfs, seahorse

Using Nautilus on Ubuntu 20.04, I use a NFS connection to a server for which I have opend through `Other Locations`> `Connect to server` and that I have added to **Nautilus bookmarks**.

Now that I wish to use different credentials, I can't seem to make Nautilus forget the ones I was using. I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/236437) that **Seahorse** should contain them, but it doesn't.

So, where are they stored?

**Edtit 1**: I have rewritten title and first paragraph to focus on the "Other location" and bookmark aspects of the question. As suggested by @user68186 I have **deleted the bookmark** and all mention to this serveur in the "recent servers" mentioned in the dropdown of the "Connect to server" field.

I have rebooted and the credentials are somehow still there because when I try to reconnect to the server, no credentials are asked, it connects directly.

Following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143127/save-and-restore-nautilus-server-connection-bookmarks), I have explored gtk* hidden files in my home directory and removed remaining mentions to the server in `~ /.config/gtk-3.0/servers` (note: there are none in `~ /.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`). But after rebooting: it still connects directly.

Comment: did you create a mount point for the nfs share under `/media/[user_name]` or similar and then mount the share in `fstab`? [This reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104308/nautilus-connect-to-server-nfs#1180977) might provide some clues.

Comment: not manually. I did all through the Nautilus interface. I will check anyway

Comment: other than that, you might find the password in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` (note the case).

Comment: Nope, nothing was added to my ```fstab```, nor to my ```/media```, and ```system-connections``` only mentions network connections such as ethernet, VPN or wifi.

Comment: Are you asking about using the **Other Locations** tab on the left margin of Nautilus to create a bookmark? If this is the case please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1364602/edit) and make this clear. In Nautilus you can't edit a bookmark after it is created. You have to delete the old one and create a new one with the new credentials. Let me know if this solves your problem. I will then turn this comment to an answer you can accept.

Comment: Still no luck. I have edited my question and added Edit 1 to detail my further investigation.